# Same Query behaving differently when executed from JPA or directly in the DB

Tags: jpa, db2

I have the following JPQL Query

```
    SELECT g                                        
    FROM MyEntity g
    WHERE g.fieldA      = :parA
    AND (g.pk.fieldB = :parB
       OR ' ' = :parB  )
```

after some trial I understood the problem is

```
OR ' ' = :parB
```

Suppose fieldB is defined as CHAR 3 in the database.

If I use

```
 parB = " "
```

the query works as expected, but if

```
parB = "abc"
```

I get an SQL Error (*DB2 error CODE -302: THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE*)

I can imagine the problem is in the length of ' ' compared to "abc", what I not really understand is why.. I copied the generated sql and if I execute it using for example Squirrel SQL it works nice:

```
OR ' ' = 'abc'
```

doesn't make any problem.

Can you please explain me what happens with the string when the query is prepared? Is it possible to adjust this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Java string of 3 Unicode characters can be up to 12 bytes in length. The size of a DB2 column is specified in bytes. In other words, a `CHAR(3)` column (3 bytes) may not accept a Java string of 3 Unicode characters (3-12 bytes).

Comment: But then shouldn't also g.pk.fieldB = :parB also fail when parB="abc"?